# c++ reading from a file does not work

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I was trying to read from a file and basically my text file is like this;

```
23 4 * 19 2 - + #
6 3 -  #
36 #
```

I am trying to read them from a file by ignoring # at the end of the file. I do not want to take `#`. After that, I want to store it in my queue.Here is part of my code like this; When I display my queue it still takes the `#`. I could not figure out why. I would be happy if you help me

```
while (!myFile.eof()) {
        getline(myFile, a, ' ');
        if (a != str4) {
            q.enqueue(a);
        }
        else {
            cout << " " << endl;
        }
    }
    q.display(cout);
```

Comment: How about using getline(myFile, a, '#'); ?

Comment: Using `!myFile.eof()` as loop condition doesn't seem good. try `while(getline(myFile, a, ' ')) {` and remove `getline` inside the loop. (I post this as comment because I didn't test this)

Comment: Have you considered regex? it can help you

Comment: @kvr, your suggested solution may fail under certain circumstances. As OP suggested that OP wants to ignore anything after # sign. e.g. ` 123 # 123`. in this case, stream will read until # which will be 123 and after # it will read 123 again. In other words, it will not ignore anything after # sign.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method is to read the text line into a string.  Next find the `#` symbol and erase all characters in the string after the `#`.

```
std::string test_string = "help fred # not fred.\n";
const std::string::size_type position = test_string.find_first("#");
test_string.erase(position, test_string.length() - position);
std::cout << "After truncation, string is: " << test_string << "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cleanup your data using regex:

```
    std::smatch _match;
    std::regex line_regex("(.*)#");

    string line;

    while(getline(myfile,line))
    {
        std::regex_search(line, _match, line_regex);
        if (_match.size() > 0)
        {
            cout << _match[1].str() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Regex will ignore anything after #. Based on sample contents of file, output will be

> Input contents:

```
23 4 * 19 2 - + #
6 3 -  # 23244
36 #
```

> Output:

```
23 4 * 19 2 - + 
6 3 -  
36
```

Comment: The data looks like input to a postfix calculator - a typical student assignment.  I don't know if the student has learned about regular expressions at this point in the course.

Comment: So the recommendation here is to use a regular expression to detect lines that end with `#`? Definitely overkill. `std::string::find` can do exactly the same thing without all the overhead.

Comment: @PeteBecker, with all due respect. question wasn't what is best or performant method to detect specific end of line character. Regex is one of many tools providing solution to problem OP mentioned above. Regex might not be a great choice in this particular case, but see it's flexibility.